# Twitterizer 2; Argument null exception

Tags: vb.net, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitterizer

I 'm a newbie to twitter api/twitterizer. I get the following exception for the code shown below. The error occurs when i request access token. Any suggestion on how to fix this?? 
I downloaded the latest dll(2.3.1) from the twitterizer website.

***{"Value cannot be null. Parameter name: String"}***

```
 Dim OAuthTokens As New OAuthTokens
    Dim accessToken As New Twitterizer.OAuthTokenResponse
            accessToken = OAuthUtility.GetAccessToken(ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecretkey, "oauth_token", "oauth_verifier")
```

thanks

Comment: I have posted the same question on twiiterizer forum and expect to get some answers there ... here is the link http://forums.twitterizer.net/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=441

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said on the forums, the oauth_token and oauth_verifier are given to you in previous steps of the authorization process. Calling the GetAccessToken method is the last step in the process.

Here's an over-simplification of the steps:
 1. Get a request token
 2. Send/Redirect the user to the authorization/authentication url
 3. (The user logs in, grants you access, and Twitter directs them back to your application)
 4. Exchange the request token for an access token

Comment: thanks, it worked. i made a mistake while registering the app...it should have been set as browser instead was desktop. Secondly i ran into an issue when i had my callback as localhost. I fixed the latter problem by changing it to http://api.twitter.com